# What is counterpart of XSLT (transforming XML to HTML) for JSON data files?

Tags: xml, json, xslt

XML files are useful, they have a schema (XSD) and browsers support natively viewing them if an XSLT file is in the same folder (or linked correctly).

But JSON is a more compact and used more and more.

What is counterpart of XSLT in JSON data world and is there native browser support to display large-ish JSON file in a nice formatted way in a browser or across different OSs/browsers.

Comment: Generate an XML from a JSON string, and XSLT it. Seriously though, if you are comparing JSON to XML in this way, you just need to get more experienced with both, in order to see how different they are and what must be used where.

Comment: The files in XML is 100MB+ till 1GB (data submission to FDA) and I think JSON file sizes would be smaller. But then we loose the benefit of viewing them in browser completely. I do know those technologies enough, I think.

Comment: here is an example of the file:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8_5z3UBMNMWcGJYbVdjVFB4TGc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Gotta agree with GSerg. I don't know of anything remotely as powerful as XSLT for use with JSON. That's what you get for using buzzword-de-jour as your data format...

Comment: Aside from the fact whether it's appropriate or not to use json for the files: no, there isn't cross-browser thing for json as css is for html or xslt is for xml. Serving as plain text would be readable, but not that fancy (who cares about fancy?), for anything else you have to process the files on the server first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest answer is probably Javascript, however there is no declarative, domain specific language as ubiquitous <sup>*</sup> as XSLT for transforming JSON objects. The only really way to transform JSON objects is by using a standard programming language that is supported in your environment.

But even then you don't get the power of declarative templates that makes XSLT (on one hand) so easy and more imprtantly predictible to use.

<sup>* While Haskell, ML and the like are quite popular declarative languages, they aren't closely related to any one particular data format. Whereas XSLT is is intrinsically tied to XML.</sup>